# Is it possible to drop and consume self at the end of scope at the same time?

Tags: rust, destructor, move-semantics, raii

Given a struct, how can a function be written so that it is automatically called at end of scope, consuming `self` rather than using `&mut self` (unlike `Drop::drop`)?

I would like to call other functions within that destructor that will consume each field of the struct, and I would like the destructor to be called automatically.

Comment: _"consuming `self` rather than `&mut self` (unlike `Drop::drop`)"_ I'm afraid that we cannot understand what you are trying to do without a concrete example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Linked to the wrong question? That’s the same one as the one I marked mine as duplicate of?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with a combination of a placeholder value, `mem::replace` and `mem::forget`:

```
use std::mem;

struct Foo;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let to_drop = mem::replace(self, Foo); // a placeholder with empty/default members
        to_drop.dropping_function();
    }
}

impl Foo {
    fn dropping_function(self) {
        println!("dropping Foo!");
        // call other destructors here
        mem::forget(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo;
}  // dropping Foo!
```

Be warned, though (citing the [docs of `mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.forget.html)):

> Takes ownership and "forgets" about the value **without running its destructor**.

Which means you need to make sure to drop everything containted in `Foo` yourself.

Comment: It compiles and runs the function, but segfaults afterwards in my use case. So, what would you recommmend? Just leave it as an explicit destructor?

Comment: I guess the best recommendation is probably to switch the other destructors to use `&mut self`, so everything would "just work". Otherwise, some pieces of the code be helpful to suggest a different solution.

Comment: The struct is intended to wrap some functionality of `gfx_hal`. Each field of it is destroyed with a corresponding `gfx_hal::Backend::destroy_*` which moves and consumes the field, so I can't change it. I'm guessing the best I can do is forgo RAII and write an explicit `destroy` function that calls `gfx_hal`'s `destroy`s?

Comment: And that doesn't cause a segfault anymore?